# Can't push into array of reference. Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I don't know why but I can't use the push methode on the array userfound.articles.

```
    app.post("/article", function (req, res){
        userModel.find({username : req.body.username}, function (err, userfound){
                var newArticle = new articleModel({
                    title : req.body.title,
                    text : req.body.text,
                    creator : userfound._id
                });

                newArticle.save(function (err, article){
                        userfound.articles.push(article); //Error : Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
                        userfound.save();
                        res.send("Article enregistré : " + userfound.articles);
                });
        });
    }
});
```

And this is my Schema code.

```
    var userSchema = new Schema ({
    username : { type : String, required : true, unique : true},
    password : { type : String, required : true},
    isAdmin : Boolean,
    comments : [{type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "Comment"}],
    articles : [{type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "Article"}],
    created_at : {type : Date, default : Date.now},
    modified_at : Date
});
```

Userfound is defined but the array of reference is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`find`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) provides its results to the callback as an array of documents, so `userfound` is an array which is why it doesn't have an `articles` property.

Use [`findOne`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) instead so that `userfound` is the single doc you're looking up:

```
userModel.findOne({username : req.body.username}, function (err, userfound){ ...
```

Note that `userfound` will be `null` if the user wasn't found.